# Generate API keys with JWT and regenerate the same key when needed

Tags: security, jwt, api-key

I recently found my self in need of developing a public API for my application. I developed my application with `node.js` and `mongodb`. After some research, I decided to use `jwt` for generating API keys for users and authentication. For authenticating `jwt` tokens, they come with the benefit of not needing to store them in a database, as they can be decoded and verified without knowing the exact generated token.

But I see that lots of applications show the users their API keys in the application dashboard, so I need to actually store the token in order to show them to the users later on. I know that storing tokens is a bad idea and in case of a database breach, it could let the hackers impersonate others with the API keys.

So long story short I am trying to find a way to not to store the exact tokens, but store only the payload in the database and every time users request their API keys I just generate the same one with a *SECRET* and pass it to them. I currently find that if on the signing token step, I pass the same payload with the same `iat` (issued at) every time, the generated token will be the same every time. So by saving the `iat` with the payload data in the database, I can generate the exact token every time.

Here is my `mongoose` schema:

```js
var KeySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, default: 'API Key' },
  active: { type: Boolean, default: true },
  iat: { type: Date, required: true },
  project: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Project', required: true },
});
```

And this is how I generate the same token with `jsonwebtoken` npm package:

```js
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

jwt.sign({ project, iat: CONST_TIMESTAMP }, config.secrets.session);
```

---

**Now my questions are:**

- Does this approach is a good approach or is there a better way to achieve this?
- Is there any good practice for generating API keys without storing them?
- Does this even necessary (considering if there ever be any database beach, all of the data is already stolen)?
- Is there any method other than using `jwt` to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

JWT is a standard approach for the given objective and for you I would recommend to use asymmetric signing key.

The advantage of this would be the consumers or clients will need to trust the issuer and there are multiple ways in which the public part of the key can be distributed.

So this does away with the requirement of key regeneration , also you can use the standard techniques for securing the private part of the signing key.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will give asymmetric signing key a go and see whats happens.